# JavaScript undefined is not a function (using the splice function)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to push "lene"(its just a test sample) into the variable "q". For some reason this is what my browser mentions:

```
Javascript highscore.html:24 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
Javascript highscore.html:145 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The second error, on line 145 is a because of the first error. I have marked line 24 in the comments here:

```
var q = [{
    TernRank: 2,
    TernVan: '03/12/2014',
    TernTot: '01/01/2015',
    TernDagen: 1
}, {
    TernRank: 3,
    TernVan: '08/01/2014',
    TernTot: '01/01/2015',
    TernDagen: 1
}, {
    TernRank: 1,
    TernVan: '03/12/2014',
    TernTot: '01/01/2015',
    TernDagen: 1
}, {
    TernRank: 4,
    TernVan: '03/12/2014',
    TernTot: '01/01/2015',
    TernDagen: 1
}];




DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    d1i = new Date(q[i].TernVan)
    d2i = new Date(q[i].TernTot)

    days_passedi = Math.round((d2i.getTime() - d1i.getTime()) / DAY)
    q[i].splice(3, 0, "Lene"); //This is line 24
};
```

The line 24 does works if I remove the "[i]".
Does anyone know why it's causing the error or/and how to fix it?

Comment: q[i] isn't an array. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: You do declare `i`, `DAY`, `d1i`, `d2i`, `days_passed1`, and such somewhere, right? Because if not, your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q` is an array, and `q[i]` is an object.

Only arrays have the method `.splice` by default: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

If you wish to *add* 'Lene' to the `q` array, the easiest way would be:

```
q.push('Lene');
```

Alternatively if you *really* want to make the splice work, you may want to do this:

```
q.splice(i, 0, 'Lene');
```

Which will add the element 'Lene' at index `i` in the `q` array.  Or you may want to do something like this:

```
q.splice(q.length + 1, 0, 'Lene');
```

Which is basically the same as `q.push`

Comment: *"well, strings do as well"*. Are you sure ? A string being immutable, this would useless

Comment: That'll be my silly brain conflating splice and slice!  Edited.